# What is the meaning of the words here?

Tags: linear-algebra, unitary-matrices, quantum-computation

I'm not sure what the meaning of the question is, and I need some help understanding what I'm even trying to do. The unitary operator in question is in $U(4)$

The question is: "Decompose the above unitary operator as a product of unitary operators, each which acts only on a two-dimensional subspace of the Hilbert space"

My confusion comes from "acts only on a two-dimensional subspace of the Hilbert space" - what does this mean, and what does it imply I should be doing in my question? Does it mean I need to use matrices with columns 3 and 4 filled with zeroes?

I'm confused and my lecturer is terrible. Please help.

Comment: Suppose $V$ is the subspace in question, and $V^\top$ is its orthogonal complement. Then your unitary operator should act as the identity on $V^\top$ but not on $V$ itself. (Compare a rotation around the $z$-axis: It leaves $e_z$ unchanged and acts only on the 2D subspace of $e_x,e_y.$) A likely scenario is that the first unitary acts on $V$ and the second acts on $V^\top$.

Comment: Agree with the previous comment although it isn't clear to me that the two subspaces need to be a space $V$ and its orthocomplement $V^{\perp}$, or just a two-dimensional subspace $V$ together with another two-dimensional space $W$.  In either case it seems like the statement that a unitary $U$ "acts on only" a subspace $W$ is intended to mean that the restriction of $U$ to the orthocomplement $W^{\perp}$ of $W$ is the identity operator (perhaps also that $U$ does not fix any element of $W$ other than $0$). Formally, any operator on a Hilbert space is a map on the entire Hilbert space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fleshing out the comments in a bit of detail.

I assume $U(4)$ is the group of $4 \times 4$ unitary matrices acting on the Hilbert space $H = \mathbb{C}^4$.  I like using $U$ for unitary operators, though, so I won't write $U(4)$ again (When I say "unitaries" without other qualification, I just mean elements of that-named set.)

If $U$ is the unitary in your question, in the "likely scenario" identified in Semiclassical's comment above, the question is basically asking to to find a basis in which you can write $U$ as a block sum of $2 \times 2$ unitary matrices, i.e., a unitary matrix $V$ (representing a change of basis) for which
$$
U = V^* \begin{pmatrix} U_1 & 0 \\ 0 & U_2 \end{pmatrix} V,
$$
where $U_1$ and $U_2$ are $2 \times 2$ unitary matrices (and $0$ denotes the $2 \times 2$ zero matrix).

Put another way, the question is to find a coordinates in which $U$ acts separately as unitary transformations of the first two coordinates and the second two coordinates.

To connect this to the phrasing of the problem, if you have a factorization of this form, then $U$ is a product of two unitaries, $W_1 = V^* \begin{pmatrix} U_1 & 0 \\ 0 & I \end{pmatrix} V$, and $W_2 = V^* \begin{pmatrix} I & 0 \\ 0 & U_2 \end{pmatrix} V$.  In the coordinates of your new basis (which probably won't be the standard basis), $W_1$ leaves the second two coordinates alone, while $W_2$ leaves the first two coordinates alone.

Or in slightly more spatial terms: let $S$ be the span of the first two elements of your basis.  Then the span of the second two elements of the basis is $S^{\perp}$ (see comments above).  Since $W_1$ fixes $S^{\perp}$, it may make sense to say that $W_1$ "acts only on $S$," and similarly it may make sense to say that $W_2$ "acts only on" $S^{\perp}$.

It may mean that your instructor meant something less restrictive, where the two-dimensional subspaces for your unitaries may not need to be complementary to one another.  But I agree with Semiclassical that this is the most likely interpretation.

Comment: this is super detailed, thanks!